# v4l2-ctl exposure_absolute setting fails

Tags: command-line, webcam

I'm trying to use this command to set a C922 webcam under Ubuntu 16.04

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_auto=1
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=10
```

Sometimes it is successful, sometimes it isn't.

For example,

```
$>v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_auto=1
$>v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=10   .....ok
$>v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=10   **.....sometimes failed**
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: failed: Input/output error
exposure_auto: Input/output error*
$>v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=10   **.......sometimes failed**
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: failed: Input/output error
exposure_auto: Input/output error*
$>v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=10   .....ok
```

I don't know why, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `exposure_auto` to `1` is in fact the right setting in order to set `exposure_absolute` on my camera. This looks like some process is changing your `exposure_auto` value in the background. If you encounter

```
$>v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_auto=1
...
$>v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=exposure_absolute=10
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: failed: Input/output error
exposure_auto: Input/output error*
```

again, then re-check your value for `exposure_auto` by using

```
v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls
```

If the value of `exposure_auto` has changed indeed, try to find out where this comes from.

Also check your device "before" and "after" (using `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`), especially if you have more than one camera (e. g. built-in plus USB). You can always make sure to address the right hardware by setting the `--device` argument, like:

```
v4l2-ctl --device /dev/videoX --set-ctrl=exposure_auto=1
```

with `videoX` being the placeholder for your actual device (may be `video0` for example).

In a similar case, I encountered:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=white_balance_temperature=3000
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: failed: Input/output error
white_balance_temperature: Input/output error
```

and I fixed it by setting

```
$ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=white_balance_temperature_auto=0
```

Comment: Following this advice, indeed clearly I get the value of _exposure_absolute_ reverted to its default after actually using the camera through OpenCV. This is consistent regardless the value I set for _exposure_auto_priority_. The new values must be rejected (reset) at some level by the intervening driver library used by OpenCV (in my case V4L2) or by the hardware. Maybe that happens when the frame rate is selected, as part of making the exposure rate match the frame rate, and I can only wonder if this was meant to be tweaked or not until I tried their Windows camera settings application.